# reverse a linked list error

Tags: c, linked-list

What is wrong with the following function that I have written to reverse a singly-linked list?

```
struct ListNode* reverse_ll(struct ListNode *head)
{
    struct ListNode *temp,*node,*prev;
    temp=head->next;
    head->next=NULL;
    prev=head;
    while(temp)
    {
        node=temp->next;
        temp->next=prev;
        prev=temp;
        temp=node;  
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that there's something wrong with it?

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What incorrect output does it give?

Comment: Can you please show us the definition of the ListNode struct?

Comment: only the first element is printed.as for the definition here it is   struct ListNode{ int data;struct ListNode *next;}

Comment: Have you considered that there might be a bug in the code to print the list?  Can you give us that code?

Comment: void printlist(struct ListNode *head){ struct ListNode * curr;curr=head;while(curr->next){printf("%d",curr->data);curr=curr->next;}}

Comment: Please **edit your post** to add the code used to print the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your code to reverse the list works if you don't forget to assign the new `head` pointer:

```
head = reverse_ll(head);
```

As @user3553031 already suspected, your `printlist` function does not work correctly. It will not print the last element. Change the condition for `while`. You also don't need the `head´ variable here:

```
void printlist(struct ListNode *curr)
{
    while (curr) {
        printf("%d ", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Lastly, a note about consistency: If your function to reverse a list is called `reverse_ll`, your printing function should probably be called `print_ll`.